# Error in kibana "Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

It's giving the below error:

```
 log   [04:38:27.634] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss
  log   [04:38:27.654] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui
  log   [04:38:44.106] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [04:38:44.108] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "endpoint" is disabled.
  log   [04:38:44.110] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "ingestManager" is disabled.
  log   [04:38:44.116] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "lists" is disabled.
  log   [04:38:46.997] [warning][legacy-service] Some installed third party plugin(s) [xpack_main]
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but a quick Google of " Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss" came up with some issues/fixes. Have you looked at those?

Answer (score 0):

Need to run all the below steps one by one :
Go to all bin location and run the below command

- run elasticsearch.bat command.
- run kibana.bat
- run logstash.bat -f logstash.conf
- run filebeat.exe -c filebeat.yml